# Unable to compile Android project due to a java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

When trying to compile the Android project from the Android Developers guide about Compose Basics I've been unable to compile the solutions due to the same exception:
`java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: G:\My Drive\Codes\Android\Lemonade\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\debug\out\com\example\lemonade`

Sometimes the compiler is able to run on the emulated device running android 14 but most often than not returns an error

I've tried removing the file that the exception highlights, cleaning and rebuilding, removing the Gradle folder and reinstalling it, restarting Android Studio, restarting my computer, wiping the emulator data and trying to run it in my phone, and none seem to work.